# How to resolve the error with the flowable/work-views library?

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, npm, flowable

I'm integrating the FlowableFlowApp React component from @flowable/work-views into my web application to open the Flowable app view. While 'npm run server' successfully displays the empty app view (which is the current expected behavior), I'm encountering errors in the command prompt:

**ERROR in node_modules/@flowable/work-views/typings.d.ts(6,13): error TS1005: ‘=’ expected.
node_modules/@flowable/work-views/typings.d.ts(6,35): error TS1005: ‘;’ expected.**

The same errors occur when I execute 'npm run build' in production mode.

My setup includes React 16, Flowable 3.13, and TypeScript 3.2.4. Upgrading React and TypeScript isn't feasible due to the application's scale and extensive dependencies.

Since my web application deployment involves packaging both React and Angular code, resolving these errors is crucial for the functionality of the Flowable app view. Any help in addressing these issues would be highly appreciated.

To troubleshoot the error, I experimented with one potential solution: I referred to the package.json file in the node_modules/@flowable/work-views directory, which lists various dependencies, devDependencies, and peerDependencies. I installed all these dependencies to see if it would resolve the issue. However, despite this attempt, I'm still facing the same error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.